# Learning more about String theory

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, education

I know the concept behind String Theory. But I was wondering if anyone knows of a good place to start learning more about the theoretical physics behind it? Maybe a book someone can recommend to me! I have a strong mathematical background, so something abstract is fine for me. I also know quite a bit about physics.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29007/
What level are you?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27760/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an overview over string theory without any! mathematical background, I can still recommend Brain Greens "the elegant universe".

A real book on String theory is "Barton Zwiebach- A first course in string theory"
It starts very slow and develops the math behind the theory from the very beginning. Even if you have a strong mathematical background, I think it's worth to read it, because it is completly adapted to what you need in string theory. I didn't finish it but I liked it.