# Advanced string theory book recommendations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft

Let's say I fully understand Polchinski books on string theory

Are there any recommended and more advanced book on strings?

Comment: Honestly, there isn't much else once you get through both volumes of Polchinski. You could try reading GSW or BBS for alternative perspectives. Anything beyond Polchinski is research level and at that point, you only learn what is specifically needed for your research.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27760/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Start writing a solution manual to the problems from his two volumes which as of yet don't have solutions published in the web.

Comment: According to this you've got a lot of problems to solve... https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.4408

Comment: Nice idea, I actually have few of them that were given to me in a course.